# Generating random tree branch

Tags: algorithm, random, generator, fractals, procedural-generation

I want to generate (an image of) a single branch of a tree (the "[woody plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree)" kind). Maybe similar to [this branch](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/113206/113206,1200998214,2/stock-vector-vector-of-a-tree-branch-silhouette-with-persimmon-fruit-8761780.jpg), or [this one](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb_377/1237695171ptIMv8.jpg).

I need it to be interesting but simple, so just one branch, with a few turns, and only a few splits (where it changes from one limb into two). It should start with one fat branch and split off into a few thin branches. I am not worried about leaves, as I am thinking that leaves are quite a separate issue, so can be handled later.

Where should I start? What is involved in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely the best/easiest way to go is [Context Free](https://www.contextfreeart.org/) fractal image generator.

Here's something to get you started (hit Render until you like it):

[image: tree]

```
startshape TREE

rule TREE {
    BRANCH {}
}

rule BRANCH {
    NEXT {r -1}
}
rule BRANCH {
    NEXT {r 1}
}
rule BRANCH .01 {
    NEXT {r 45}
}
rule BRANCH .01 {
    NEXT {r -45}
}
rule BRANCH .01 {
    NEXT {r 30}
    NEXT {r -30}
}

rule NEXT {
    CIRCLE {}
    BRANCH {y .3 s .996}
}
```